# Unable to migrate to JBoss EAP 7 because of Tapestry

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, tapestry, jboss-eap-7

I am currently migrating a prject containng two web applications from tomEE to JBoss EAP7.

I've succesfully deployed my two applications however when I try to access them at their respective URI I get the following :

For the admin app I have "Forbidden" on its URI.

And I get this trace in my Eclipse : 
`admin` https://pastebin.com/QKTRFQGv

For the wli app I have a part of the error trace on its URI.

And I get this trace in the server.log : 
`wli` https://pastebin.com/YSRbpsf8

Moreover, I tried to use this solution:
wiki.apache.org/tapestry/HowToRunTapestry5OnJBoss7Dot1

But I didn't work at all, does anyone know how I could use this class correctly ?

Thank you in advance for your help and advices. Do not hesitate to ask me if you need more informations.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the root problem is, but it looks like you've got a very old version of Tapestry (5.1.0.5, from 2009!) and you're trying to use it with a modern version of Java (JDK 1.8). I don't think that can work. You'll need to upgrade Tapestry to at least 5.3.8 for full JDK 1.8 compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to update Tapestry to 5.3.8 however it seems my project needs imports from a custom version of Tapestry5 provided by my company. Thus when I upgrade the Tapestry version in my POM I lose the "custom imports" that I couldn't replace with new classes from Tapestry 5.3.8. I don't really know if I can even upgrade Tapestry, but for the first app (admin) Tapestry seems to work just fine with java8.